# declaring a non-static member array of template function pointers. (c++14)

Tags: c++, templates, static, c++14, member

Is there any way to have `funci` be non-static? Please show declaration, initialization, and calling.

Also, is there any way to get rid of the redundant `<decltype(i)>` in the function call?

Finally, I'm not sure function pointer is an accurate name for what this is. I'm curious if anyone has an argument for if the label is accurate or what label should be used.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void makeit(T t){
    cout << typeid(t).name() << " func" << endl;
}

struct A{

    using Func = void(*)(int);
    const Func func[1] = {&makeit<int>};

    template <typename T>
    using Funci = void (*)(T);
    //works fine

    template <typename T>
    const static Funci<T> funci[1];
    //works with out-of-class definition below

    //template <typename T>
    //const Funci<T> funci2[1] = {&makeit};
    //compiler error: member 'funci2' declared as template

};

template <typename T>
const typename A::template Funci<T> A::funci[] = {&makeit};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    A ay;
    int i;
    double d;

    (*ay.func[0])(i);
    (*A::funci<decltype(d)>[0])(d);
    //(*ay.funci2<decltype(d)>[0])(d);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
i func
d func
```

Comment: Do you want it to be non-static AND be a constexpr? It doesn't make sense for a constexpr to be a constexpr because a constexpr must be evaluable at compile-time.

Comment: @iAdjunct It does not need to be constexpr.

Comment: this looks like it might be an XY problem. what exactly are you trying to do? what is the real purpose of `makeit`? if `funci` is not static, then to call it you must provide an instance of type `struct B`. What is your intention to provide that? You want `struct B` also to be a statically initialized object? If it is not then it cannot really be a template parameter. It's not clear to me what kind of answer you are expecting. *Why* do you want funci to be non-static? Usually if something can be static then you want it to be, so it doesn't have ignored arguments.

Comment: Finally you should tag this question not just with C++, but with C++11 or C++14 depending on what standard you are using.

Comment: @ChrisBeck The instance of `Struct B` I want to use is static, namely `b`. I would like `fucci` to be non-static not for functionality, but for syntax. I would like to avoid out of class initialization for `fucci`. However, I cannot figure out how to make `fucci` non-static. I'm thinking it might be related to the keyword `using` with templates.

Comment: so i don't understand also why you make it an array, why can it not simply be a function pointer? unless in your application you really need it to be an array

Comment: @ChrisBeck It needs to be an array. Is the answer different if it is not? Of course there are many ways to get the functionality of an array.

Comment: I think it's too hard right now to understand what the design parameters are, you seem to have a lot of code in the example that is just boiler-plate and isn't doing much of anything, and it's not clear why it needs to be there. Someone who wants to understand the problem and give a simple answer isn't going to understand what changes are acceptable in an answer. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Can you describe a concrete programming task, or is this question really just "how can I fiddle with the syntax minimally to make X compile?"

Comment: @ChrisBeck I cleared up the question and added a comment in the code showing exactly what compiler error I'm talking about.

Comment: ok i see. so the issue is, when you declare a struct, the type of every member variable of it must be known. the reason is, the size of every member variable of it must be known. otherwise, the size of the struct cannot be determined. for, if the struct is instantiated on the stack, how much should the stack pointer be moved? if the compiler cannot determine that as a constant then it cannot generate code for the function. One approach you could take is to make struct B a template, taking typename T as a parameter. But I think that might not achieve what you want.

Comment: @ChrisBeck okay I think you've answered it. But I'm looking for an explanation as to what is really happening with the templated `using`. Does it implicitly make a new instance of `funci` for each type? So the problem is that it doesn't know how many types there will be during the compile time of it's unit? I simplified the code for a final time.

Comment: `using` has nothing to do with the issues here, as far as I can see. The `using Funci` in this program is an *alias template*, i.e. a *template* that produces *type aliases* (typedefs). `Funci<double>` is equivalent to `void(*)(double)`, `Funci<int>` == `void(*)(int)` and so on. All the issues are rooted in declaring `funci` as a *variable template*. A variable template is a template that produces variables, or in this case: it produces non-static data members. The compiler produces a non-static data member for each different argument used to instantiate `funci`.

Comment: If you want an array into which you can store different kinds of function pointers (like `void(*)(int)` and `void(*)(double)`), then you need some form of *type erasure*. This is already implemented in the [`std::function` wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). If you don't know it already, then please take a look at it. If you do know it already, and you do want to store different kinds of function pointers in an array, please describe why `std::function` doesn't fit your purpose.